# Windows Phone 8 application does not load the mainpage.xaml, gets stuck at "loading"

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am getting a very weird issue with my windows phone 8 application.

After I start debugging, the emulator comes, my application gets deployed and starts running.

I debugged through app.xaml and then the debugger even hits the constructor of "Mainpage.xaml".

After I press F5 from the constructor, the emulator keeps showing "loading" screen and never really displays the mainpage.xaml UI.

[image]

This is the output from "Debug"

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain): Loaded
'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the 
debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is   
optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the 
debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the 
debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the 
debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded  
'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the 
debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\Data\Programs\{CBED48CE-DB64-44F3-9F60-7BCFF4093AAB}\Install\Tee.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded  
'C:\windows\system32\System.Data.Linq.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and 
the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and 
the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is 
optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is 
optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the 
debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded   
'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is 
optimized 
and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x8f4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x8fc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x988 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x998 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x9a0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

The startup object is correctly set to "app" and in the manifest the navigation page is set to "mainpage.xaml" and which is why the debugger does hit the constructor of "Mainpage.xaml".

What can be the problem?

Comment: Any code in the constructor of the app or the mainpage? Replace the mainpage with a standard, empty page and test. Then slowly add back the features of the mainpage

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd yes there is code in App.xaml constructor for creating database. If I debug through it, it works fine! I will try your suggestion of starting off with empty page and the adding back features

Answer (score 2):

Oh .... it turns out that I ran VS 2012 code analysis on my application code after I was finished and it added a null check in the "CompleteInitializePhoneApplication" method which resulted in this error.

In App.xaml, it should be

```
        // Do not add any additional code to this method
    private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
        if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
            RootVisual = RootFrame;

        // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
        RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
    }
```

But either Resharper or the code analysis added this stupid null check to it which turned it into this:

```
        // Do not add any additional code to this method
    private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
        if (RootVisual != null && RootVisual != RootFrame)
            RootVisual = RootFrame;

        // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
        RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
    }
```

So basically my RootVisual was never getting set to begin with.

Thanks @ErnodeWeerd for your suggestion to start from scratch.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Did the tools suggest or change the code?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I dont remember, but usually Resharper does not directly change the code, I might have accidentally pressed "Alt+Space" to get that code changed ... so yeah, effectively my bad! :)